# Filtrar dados de um JSON

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Gostaria filtrar alguns dados de um JSON retornado de uma consulta, afim de retorna uma lista com o titulo e valor de cada propriedade.

código que estou tentando modificar:

```
      var titulo = Object.keys(retorno);

      for(var i = 0; i < titulo.length; i++){

           console.log(titulo.i);

      }


    var conteudo = Object.values(retorno);

 $("table").append(`<tr id='t_titulo'>
                        <th>${titulo}</th>
                            </tr>
                        <td id='t_conteudo'>
                       ${conteudo}</td>
                    </tr>`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui encontrar

```
      var tamPerson = Object.keys(retorno).length;

      $.each(retorno, function(key, val) {
     $("table").append("<tr id='t_titulo'><th>" + key + "</th></tr><td id='t_conteudo'>" + val + "</td></tr>");

});
```

Comment: Voce pode fechar a pergunta ou postar o objeto para complementar a sua questão.